# Sessions Sharing between two web applications : tomcat

Tags: java, session, tomcat, share

Hello friends!
             I am working on a project where I am suppose to share sessions between two applications in different context, both are deployed on Tomcat, I did context sharing (session sharing on single instance of tomcat) but we need to do this on multiple instances of tomcat, any help will be highly appreciated

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find documentation for Tomcat clustered sessions [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html).

Comment: those are two different applications and clustering is only possible when it is a single app (may be on multiple instances of a container)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using something like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/), [Terracotta](http://ehcache.org/documentation/distributed_caching_with_terracotta.html), [Redis](http://redis.io/), etc.